# How to fill the fillable PDF in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf

PDF Expert is an iPhone application that enables user to fill the editable PDF and can save it. means It is editable form.

I used `UIWebView` to show the PDF, It showing exactly as it is, but the text field on it is un-editable.

I tried using the `UIDocumentInteractionController`to view the pdf, It showing well, but I can't edit on that file.

In safari browser of mac It supports only viewing the file, but Google Chrome supports editing of the file. and While opening the file using Preview application on mac, It allows edition to the user and can save it.

Please suggest me, How to edit and save the file in this..

Thank you...

Comment: You will need to implement your own support for form-filling PDFs. the base support in iOS is read-only.

Comment: You mean, i have to parse the PDF using Quartz2d and constructing view  with respect to the PDF and after filling the data, I have to create a PDF, Am I right?

Comment: Or you could buy one of the PDF libraries that are available for iOS that support dealing with form-filling PDFs

Comment: If I do the above, Could I parse the text field, check box exists in PDF?... Just I got a doc http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-BAJBBFGF

Comment: I would believe that this should allow you to parse the fields, checkboxes in the PDF. You would be best experimenting with simple form-based PDFs, and working from there

Comment: Could you refer any sample for pdf parsing?

Answer (score 0):

I was after the same thing and found this to be a seemingly good solution: https://github.com/derekblair/ILPDFKit

Lets you fill in a form, access/set fields and then save out as a static copy.